# User Controls not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have an asp.net application developed using .net 1.1 . The header and footer are user controls. I need to change some text and images in the user control, but i have a limitation that I don't have visual studio 2003 installed in my machine. Now when I edit the user control  files in notepad and save it then the changes are not getting reflected in the pages. Note I need to make changes only to the UI of the user controls no code behind changes are needed. Any advice....

Comment: @lakshmi..do you have any other tools like SharpDevelop etc. With out an IDE it is very difficult to build

Comment: I need to change the UI part only not the code behind file

Comment: @Lakshmi..Even though you are changing test/images they correspond to user control. Which indeed is a server side control. So, inorder to reflect those changes, i guess you have ro rebuild your solution

Comment: @Avinash... Thanks so other than rebuilding the application there no other go right

Comment: @Lakshmi..to my knowledge..there is no way..

Answer (score 0):

The controls would need to be rebuilt, not just the source code edited.

You need to use Visual Studio

Comment: I need to change the UI part only not the code behind file

Comment: could you updated the question with exactly what you are changing?

Comment: I have to change so text and images

Comment: yeah, I meant some before/after code examples so I can try and determine why html only changes aren't being reflected in the rendered html

Comment: i want to remove some hyperlinks and replace the existing images  with the new one.